# Как высчитать корень n степени из числа

Tags: python, математика

Дана строка. Допустим: `"4*2-3√(26+1)"`.
Есть одна формула: `m**(1 / n)`. Где `m` в данном случае это `"26 + 1"`, а `n` это `3`.
Как сделать чтобы в строке был результат корня: `"4*2-3"`?

Comment: Что-то я не очень понял. Вот есть строка, в ней написано выражение. А причем тут формула, что вообще дальше происходит мне не понятно

Comment: корень n степени из числа высчитывается по вышеуказанной формуле

Comment: Мне надо фрагмент кода, который находит в любом выражении корни и высчитывает их, заранее спасибо

Comment: Ну тогда можно регуляркой найти в строке выражение с вычислением корня, и вытащить из него `m` и `n`. Попробуйте реализовать, если что-то не получится добавьте ваш код в вопрос и расскажите, что не получается. Писать весь код за вас что-то лениво

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В этом случае нужно парсить строку вручную.

Код взял отсюда https://habr.com/ru/post/273253/ и добавил ваш корень.

```
OPERATORS = {'+': (1, lambda x, y: x + y), '-': (1, lambda x, y: x - y),
             '*': (2, lambda x, y: x * y), '/': (2, lambda x, y: x / y),
             '√': (2, lambda x, y: y ** (1/x)),
}


def eval_(formula):
    def parse(formula_string):
        number = ''
        for s in formula_string:
            if s in '1234567890.':
                number += s
            elif number:
                if number.isdigit():
                    yield int(number)
                else:
                    yield float(number)
                number = ''
            if s in OPERATORS or s in "()":
                yield s
        if number:
            if number.isdigit():
                yield int(number)
            else:
                yield float(number)

    def shunting_yard(parsed_formula):
        stack = []
        for token in parsed_formula:
            if token in OPERATORS:
                while stack and stack[-1] != "(" and OPERATORS[token][0] <= OPERATORS[stack[-1]][0]:
                    yield stack.pop()
                stack.append(token)
            elif token == ")":
                while stack:
                    x = stack.pop()
                    if x == "(":
                        break
                    yield x
            elif token == "(":
                stack.append(token)
            else:
                yield token
        while stack:
            yield stack.pop()

    def calc(polish):
        stack = []
        for token in polish:
            if token in OPERATORS:
                y, x = stack.pop(), stack.pop()
                stack.append(OPERATORS[token][1](x, y))
            else:
                stack.append(token)
        return stack[0]

    return calc(shunting_yard(parse(formula)))

print(eval_("4*2-3√(26+1)"))
```

Comment: Это как то сурово и не соразмерно решаемой задаче)